# pandas dataframe to tensorflow input

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

i want to use a pandas dataset as an input to a neural net.

my neural net model is:

```
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(128, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation = "softmax"))

    model.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        loss=['binary_crossentropy'],
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    return model

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f"logs/{time.time()}", histogram_freq=1)

model = build_model()

history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=5,
    batch_size=32,
    validation_data=(
        x_val,
        y_val
    ),
    callbacks=[
        tensorboard
    ]
)
```

and i pass my dataframe as input as such:

```
y_val, x_val, y_train, x_train = test_data.drop(['gender', 
       'comorbidities_count', 'comorbidities_significant_count',
       'medication_count'],axis=1),test_data.drop(['fried'],axis=1),training_data.drop([ 'gender', 'comorbidities_count', 'comorbidities_significant_count',
       'medication_count'],axis=1),training_data.drop(['fried'],axis=1)
```

but i get this error:

ValueError: Please provide as model inputs either a single array or a list of arrays.

Does anyone know hot to turn this dataframe into an array so i can feed it? Or is there some other issue i am not in knowledge of?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
y_val, x_val, y_train, x_train = test_data.drop(['gender', 
       'comorbidities_count', 'comorbidities_significant_count',
       'medication_count'],axis=1).to_numpy().astype(np.float32) ,test_data.drop(['fried'],axis=1).to_numpy().astype(np.float32) ,training_data.drop([ 'gender', 'comorbidities_count', 'comorbidities_significant_count',
       'medication_count'],axis=1).to_numpy().astype(np.float32) ,training_data.drop(['fried'],axis=1).to_numpy().astype(np.float32)
```

The .to_numpy() function of a pd dataframe turns it into a numpy array.

Comment: now i get this: ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).

Comment: add .astype(np.float32) after every array. this will convert the arrays to float arrays

Comment: sorry but now i get: NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: logs/1577540868.3478014\train; No such file or directory [Op:CreateSummaryFileWriter]

Comment: this is caused by the tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=f"logs/{time.time()}", histogram_freq=1) line and not related to this issue

Comment: try to use log_dir="logs/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") as your log dir. For that you have to import datetime.

Comment: it doenst recognise datetime. Is it something i should import?

Comment: As I mentioned one comment above you have to import datetime

Comment: sorry but i get the same method. Is there a prefixed callback method that outputs losses and accuracy per epoch that I could use. Sorry but i find it hard to find one online

Comment: what method do you mean?

Comment: I am trying to use this for example:https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ProgbarLogger?version=stable

Comment: so i use this in callback: callbacks=[ProgbarLogger(count_samples='steps',stateful_metrics=None)
    ]  but it doesnt recognise it i get:NameError: name 'ProgbarLogger' is not defined

Comment: from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ProgbarLogger

Comment: you have to import it